# Array permutations as i need

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Any of you may have done this type of combination i have mentioned below.

```
$data = array
(
    'a1' => array(7, 32,44),
    'a2' => array(4,44),
    'a3' => array(9,33,55)
);
```

This returns should be something like this if i try to retrieve n times. Suppose n=4 ( o to 3).

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7  // from a1
            [1] => 4  // from a2
            [2] => 9  // from a3         
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 44
            [2] => 33           
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 55           
        )


    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 44
            [2] => 9           
        )
)
```

and so on....

Comment: When assigning n-th item to the resulting array, add source item at index n modulo source array length..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6882417/342740

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array permutations in multidimensional array keeping the keys PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967587/array-permutations-in-multidimensional-array-keeping-the-keys-php)

Answer (score 3):

The `%` operation is your friend:

```
function foo($arr, $n) {
  $result = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $result[$i] = array_map(function($value) use ($i) {
      return $value[$i % count($value)];
    }, $arr);
  }
  return $result;
}

// usage:
var_dump(foo($data, 4));
```

Answer (score 3):

An interesting way to solve this is by using a [`MultipleItator()`](http://php.net/multipleiterator):

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator;

array_walk($data, function(array $item) use ($iterator) {
    // attach infinite iterators for each element
    $iterator->attachIterator(new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($item)));
});
```

It uses the [`InfiniteIterator`](http://php.net/infiniteiterator) to rewind each array when it reaches the end. This also means the iterator as a whole is infinite; using `foreach` on this will go until you kill the script, so you have to use a `for` loop:

```
$iterator->rewind()
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    print_r($iterator->current());
    $iterator->next()
}
```

Btw, you can't use [`LimitIterator`](http://php.net/limititerator) here to select the first four items, because it would throw notices if you did.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to call this operation a 'modular zip', as it works in a similar fashion to Python's `zip` function, wrapping around to the front. Uses the array `next` function instead of the numeric modulo operator, which is measurably faster.

`$array_list` should be a list of arrays; no data type checking is performed.

```
<?php

function zip_modular($len, $array_list) {  
  $out = array();

  for($n = 0; $n < $len; $n++) {
    $out[$n] = array();
    foreach($array_list as &$arr) {
      $cur = current($arr);
      if(empty($cur)) {
        reset($arr);
      }
      $out[$n][] = current($arr);
      next($arr);
    }
  }

  return $out;
}

// example
print_r(zip_modular(4, [[7, 32, 44], [4, 44], [9, 33, 55]]));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32
            [1] => 44
            [2] => 33
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 44
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 55
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 44
            [2] => 9
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: using http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list would be clearer

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós possibly, although not all of the parameters are arrays. There's also the consideration, that the OP gives the example input to be an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 function sample($len, $array_list) {  
      $out = array();
      //print_r($array_list);

       $num_arrs = count($array_list);


      for($n = 0; $n < $len; $n++) {
        $out[$n] = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_arrs; $i++) {
            // $array_list['a1'.$i];

          $cur = current($array_list['a'.$i]);
          if(empty($cur)) {
            reset($array_list['a'.$i]);
          }
          $out[$n][] = current($array_list['a'.$i]);
          next($array_list['a'.$i]);
        }
      }

      return $out;
    }

    // example
    print_r(sample(4, $data));
```